# esp32c3 how to increase num of transfer data during one handshake through AT command httpclient

Tags: python, c, iot, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using spi-at instead of uart to use httpclient command to download resource from the net.But each time the slave(esp32c3) pull up and during the handshake,it only transfer 512 Bytes to the master(STM32) which result in too much handshake event to finsh 5M data's transmission.All these events would cost lots of delay.

I have try to look up the resource code,but i couldn't find any useful msg.
Is there any way to change 512 Bytes into a larger number?Hopefully 4092 Bytes?

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You tag python, c and c++(Arduino) for your question, we have no idea what exactly you are using and how you code look like, as far as I know the stream buffer for SPI AT with ESP-IDF (that is, in c) could be 8192 bytes and TCP packet size can be configure via esp-idf config as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Sorry i'm not familiar with this platform yet.
It is C language  that i'm using.
This 8192, is it the buffer size  of the transmission between the MCU and the esp32c3? If so, does this size determine how many bytes would be transmitted 
for using at command httpclient?
Or is it between the esp32c3  and the net?